# Cover whole page with a video player

Tags: html, css, media-player, plyr

I am working on a website for my post-production company with Webflow.
I can't force the player (Plyr) to fill the whole page... The part with the player bar is outside the page. How can I get the whole player to be contained on the page?

Thanks

```
.video {
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
right: 0%;
bottom: 0%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: hi first of all you can leave out the right and bottom, and try height: 100vh